# External screen blinks on 4k resolution (3840 x 2160) on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution, monitor

Screen completely goes black for around 1 second and then display comes back without going to sleep. This is happening around every 30-40 secs and makes the display unusable.

This only happens when I switch to 4k resolution (3840 x 2160) while for other resolutions (2560 x 1440), it works fine but the text is blur. Scale is kept 100% and refresh rate @ 30 fps

The display is connected to usb type-c with display port

External Display - "LG UL850"

PC - "Dell Inspiron 5509" stock

- 11th Generation Intel Core i5-1135G7
- 8GB RAM
- Nvidia GeForce MX350

OS - "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

I checked the intel documentation for the chipset mentioned [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/208658/intel-core-i51135g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz/specifications.html) It mentions that it can support upto 4 displays with 8k (7680 x 4320) resolution @ 60Hz. So, this shouldn't be a hardware problem.

some meta that maybe helpful

```
xrandr
```

> DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
>
> 3840x2160     60.00 +  30.00
> 2560x1440     59.95*
> 1920x1080     60.00    59.94
> 1600x900      60.00
> 1280x1024     60.02
> 1280x800      59.81
> 1280x720      60.00    59.94
> 1024x768      60.00
> 800x600       60.32
> 720x480       60.00    59.94
> 640x480       60.00    59.94

```
lspci
```

> 0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)